# Can not connect to mysql server (Percona)

Tags: mysql, centos7, access-denied, percona

I have installed **percona server version 5.7** on my **centos 7**.Now when I try to issue following command to connect to the server.

> access denied for user **'root'@'localhost'**

I have tried to use the **--skip-greant-tables** to change the password and host from localhost to %.
I have tried changing the **OS hostname to localhost**.
I have also tried using **--skip-name-resolve**.

but still no chance.

any help appreciated

Comment: How did you install it?  Does the security enhancements section [here](https://www.percona.com/blog/2015/05/27/mysql-5-7-key-features/) and [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-directory-initialization-mysqld.html) help at all?

Comment: no it still doesn't work, still getting the same error 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Answer (score 6):

In Percona 5.7, the temporary password is stored in /var/log/mysqld.log so you can find it by:

```
grep 'temporary password' /var/log/mysqld.log
```

After that, you can start mysql

```
sudo systemctl start mysql
sudo /usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation
```

and use your temporary password to use.

Comment: This is the only think that actually works. Many many thanks to Tuan Ngo. You are the Man.

Answer (score 0):

After installing percona, you have to run these commands in order to set password for user root on mysql :

1- `sudo systemctl start mysql`

2- `sudo mysql_secure_installation`